# Shopify: How to return only children of specified menu/linklist?

Tags: shopify

Let's assume we have a menu:

```
Main Menu
  └ Home
  └ About Us
    └ Locations
      └ Montreal
      └ Ottawa
```

---

I would like to return links only nested below "Locations" from our "Main Menu".

Expected Output:

```
- Montreal
- Ottawa
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible only.You can just follow the below instructions and do it yourself.

Open your admin panel and open the **Navigation** part.
If you don't aware of Navigation means paste the below URL to change  main menu

https://your-domain-name.myshopify.com/admin/menus

**Note:** You must replace your-domain-name

Here you can view the Menu list, For your understanding, I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

After click the Main menu it will redirects to another page.
In that page you can able to delete or add the list items.

If you have any query means, kindly ask again.